# How to properly initialize a string

Tags: c, string, function

How would I go about defining the following string for the following function?

As of now I get the warning:

`C4047: '=' : 'const char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [4]'`

and the error:

`C2166: l-value specifies const object.`

Both in the third line of the code below:

```
uint8_t *buffer= (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
const char *stringaling= (const char *) malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
*stringaling = "fun";
newval = protobuf_writeString (buffer, stringaling);

uint32_t protobuf_writeString(uint8_t *out,const char * str)
{

      if (str == NULL)
      {
          out[0] = 0;
          return 1;
      }
      else
      {
          size_t len = strlen (str);
          size_t rv = uint32_pack (len, out);
          memcpy (out + rv, str, len);
          return rv + len;
      }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `sizeof(unit32_t)`?

Comment: @Michael what do you recommend I use

Comment: This depends on what you're trying to do. As your code is now, I don't see why you would want to allocate a string with the size of a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 4):

```
const char *stringaling= (const char *) malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
*stringaling = "fun";
```

This is not valid code. You are trying to assign to a const variable, which is illegal. Then you are trying to assign an array of characters to a character. And finally, even if you had a non-const array of characters of the right size, you still can't assign arrays, because they're not first-class values.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
char *stringaling = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
strcpy(stringaling, "fun");
```

...instead, and see if that doesn't work better. Note, however, that it's pretty much accidental that (at least usually) `sizeof(uint32_t)` happens to be the right size to hold "fun". You normally don't want to do that.

Alternatively, you may want:

```
char const *stringaling = "fun";
```

or:

```
char stringaling[] = "fun";
```

The assignment you had won't work though -- C has only the *very* most minimal support for strings built into the language; most operations (including copying a string) are normally done via library functions such as `strcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

`"fun"` is a string literal, which is essentially a `const char *`.

`stringaling` is also a `const char *`, so your third line is trying to assign a `const char *` to a `const char`, which is not going to fly.

If it's a constant string, you can just do this:

```
const char *stringaling = "fun";
```

If your input string is dynamic, you can do this:

```
char *stringaling= (char *) malloc(strlen(inputString)+1);
strcpy(stringaling, inputString);
```

Obviously, if you malloc it, you need to free it, or feel the wrath of a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to **initialize** the `char *`, you could write this instead:

`const char *stringaling = "fun";`

And here's [some reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc03iniptr.htm).

Answer (score 0):

without all the stuff you can also use:

```
newval = protobuf_writeString (buffer, "fun" );
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem:

```
const char *stringaling= (const char *) malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Several problems on this line.

First of all, you don't want to declare `stringaling` as `const char *`; you will not be able to modify whatever `stringaling` points to (IOW, `*stringaling` will not be writable).  This matters since you want to copy the contents of another string to the location pointed to by `stringaling`.  Drop the `const` keyword.

Secondly, `malloc(sizeof(uint32_t))` just happens to allocate enough bytes (4) for this particular string, but it's not clear that you *meant* to allocate 4 bytes.  When allocating memory for an array (and strings are arrays), explicitly indicate the *number of elements* you intend to allocate.

Finally, casting the result of `malloc` is considered bad practice in C.  The cast will suppress a useful diagnostic message if you forget to include stdlib.h or otherwise don't have a prototype for `malloc` in scope.  As of the 1989 standard, `malloc` returns `void *`, which can be assigned to any other object pointer type without needing to cast.  This isn't true in C++, so a cast is required there, but if you're writing C++ you should be using `new` instead of `malloc` anyway.

So, change that line to read

```
char *stringaling = malloc(LEN); // or malloc(LEN * sizeof *stringaling), but
                                 // in this case that's redundant since 
                                 // sizeof (char) == 1
```

where LEN is the number of chars you want to allocate.

The general form for a `malloc` call is

```
T *p = malloc (N * sizeof *p);
```

where `T` is the base type (`int`, `char`, `float`, `struct ...`, etc.), and `N` is the number of *elements* of type T you want to allocate.  Since the type of the expression `*p` is `T`, `sizeof *p` == `sizeof(T)`; if you ever change the type of `p`, you don't have to replicate that change in the `malloc` call itself.

Second problem:

```
*stringaling = "fun";
```

Again, there are several issues at play.  First, you cannot assign string values using the `=` operator.  String literals are array expressions, and in most contexts array expressions have their type implicitly converted ("decay") from "N-element array of T" to "pointer to T".  Instead of copying the contents of the string literal, you would be simply assigning a pointer to the first character in the string.

Which would "work" (see below), except that you're dereferencing `stringaling` in the assignment; the type of the expression `*stringaling` is `const char` (`char` after making the change I indicated above), which is not compatible for assignment with type `char *`.  If you drop the dereference operator and write

```
stringaling = "fun";
```

you'd fix the compile-time error, but now you have another problem; as mentioned above, you haven't copied the contents of the string literal "fun" to the memory block you allocated with `malloc`; instead, you've simply copied the *address* of the string literal to the variable `stringaling`.  By doing so, you lose track of the dynamically-allocated block, causing a memory leak.

In order to copy the string *contents* from one place to another, you'll have to use a library function like `strcpy` or `strncpy` or `memcpy`, like so:

```
strcpy(stringaling, "fun");
```

If `stringaling` doesn't need to live on the heap (for example, you're only using it within a single function and deallocating it before returning), you could avoid memory management completely by declaring it as a regular array of `char` and initializing it with "fun":

```
char stringaling[] = "fun";
```

This is a special case of initializing an array in a declaration, not an assignment expression, so the `=` *does* copy the contents of the string literal to the `stringaling` array.  This only works in an array declaration, however.  You can later modify the array with other string values (up to 3 characters plus the 0 terminator), but you'd have to use `strcpy` again:

```
strcpy(stringaling, "one");
```

If you don't need to modify the contents of `stringaling`, you could just do

```
const char *stringaling = "fun";
```

This copies the *address* of the string literal "fun" to the variable `stringaling`.  And since attempting to modify the contents of a string literal invokes undefined behavior, we *do* want to declare `stringaling` as `const char *` in this case; that will prevent you from accidentally modifying the string literal.